# jQuery code to be used as Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a code that I found in one of the answers on this website. I would like to know if that code can be written in simple JS or not? Also, if someone can help me understand it in terms of simple Javascript I would really appreciate your help.

The code is to fix the time lost during changing of tabs in chrome for timing functions like setTimeout and setInterval.

The code goes like this -

```
var div = $('div');
var a = 0;
var delay = (1000 / 30);
var now, before = new Date();


setInterval(function() {
    now = new Date();
    var elapsedTime = (now.getTime() - before.getTime());
    if(elapsedTime > delay)
        //Recover the motion lost while inactive.
        a += Math.floor(elapsedTime/delay);
    else
        a++;
    div.css("left", a);
    before = new Date();    
}, delay);
```

***Please note that I am a newbie to this site and therefore with my current reputation I cannot comment on that answer of the question I am referring to.***

Comment: There are only two jQuery methods used here; look up what each of them does and then find a suitable replacement. You can do it!

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand this line of code? var elapsedTime = (now.getTime() - before.getTime());

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Why now has been defined as new Date(); twice in the code above? Once in the global space and once inside of the setInterval function?

Comment: `now` is never set in the outer scope, only declared. It would be very helpful for you to read a basic JavaScript syntax tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have understood a lot about this code now. However, the one I am building myself it is not working for it! It requires a lot of high math which I am trying, but is not becoming possible. Do u want to see?

Comment: No; if you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two jquery calls in the OP's question:

1. `$('div')`
2. `div.css("left", a)`

**The first:**
`$('div')` -> `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'))`

> Return a collection of matched elements either found in the DOM based on passed argument(s) - [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

It returns a collection (array) of elements matched by the selector `'div'`. That means all `div` elements on the page.

Lets strip down the plain javascript part:

- `document.querySelectorAll('div')` select all elements on the `document` with selector `'div'`. The problem here is that `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an array. It's an array-like object.
- `[].slice` *returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
  It can take an array like object (e.g. the result of `querySelectorAll`). The result is an actual array

At this point `var div` contains an array of all `div` elements on the page.

**The second**
`div.css("left", a)`-> `div.forEach(function (item) {item.style.left = a + 'px';})`

> set one or more CSS properties for every matched element - [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

It sets a style attribute to an jQuery element. In this case, it sets the css `left` property to `a`. `a` is a number, jQuery appends `'px'` to that number to make it a string.

Lets strip down the plain javascript part:

- `div.forEach()` Loop over the `div` variable, which is now an array. For every item in the array, execute the following function:
- `function (item) { item.style.left = a + 'px'; }` This function takes a parameter (`item`). This is the a dom element, which is stored in the `div` array. Every dom element has a styles object with css properties. This function takes the `a` variable (a number) concats `'px'` to it and sets that to the `left` property.

So basically, this function loops over every item in the `div` array and sets the `styles.left` property to the `a` value.

The complete code would be:

```
var div = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
var a = 0;
var delay = (1000 / 30);
var now, before = new Date();

setInterval(function() {
    now = new Date();
    var elapsedTime = (now.getTime() - before.getTime());
    if(elapsedTime > delay)
        //Recover the motion lost while inactive.
        a += Math.floor(elapsedTime/delay);
    else
        a++;
    div.forEach(function (item) {
         item.style.left = a + 'px';
    })
    before = new Date();    
}, delay);
```

Comment: How about some text explaining why this solves OP's problem?

Comment: Can you please explain me what this line of code is doing?
var elapsedTime = (now.getTime() - before.getTime());

Comment: It's figuring out how many milliseconds have passed since the before variable was assigned to.

Comment: Why has now been defined twice as new Date(); once in the global space and once inside the setInterval function?